# One item in RecyclerView per day

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to create RecyclerView, which will show only one item per 24 hours. For example the first day, recyclerview shows item A, and at the second day shows item B. How can i do it?
Thanks in advance

[Something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuPp1.png)

Comment: If there is only one item, why would it be in a `RecyclerView`? `RecyclerView` is for showing a bunch of items in a scrollable list or grid.

Comment: a `RecyclerView` is indeed extremely pointless, unless those items do not cover enough height, so that they even would be recycled while scrolling ...this would rather be a `ViewFlipper` - but even this is overkill. a `CardView` should suffice.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler, CardView without RecyclerView?

Comment: I agree with them. No need to use RecyclerView in this case. Are your items A and B totally different or not ? If yes, you can just insert views inside your layout and make the good one visible and the others hidden. Otherwise, just update the displayed values accordingly.

Comment: @BRBR yes, just for example. it could as well a be a `Fragment` or even a `View`... while the layout is always about the same, one can reuse it and just display another day's data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a card view and vary the data displayed based on the day rather than varying which view to display in the case of a recycler view.

You can create a independent card view, it need not be in a recycler view